# Parse string using the Where-Object cmdlet

Tags: powershell

So I have this simple collection:

```
$str = "bla_sdf_r1_vrr_1.0.1", "bla_sdf_r1_trr_1.0.2"
```

If this string contains the word `vrr` i want to take the version number `1.0.1` and if this string contains the word `trr` i want to take the version number `1.0.2`

This is what I have tried and it works fine:

```
$fld = $str | Where { $_.Contains("vrr") }
$ver = $fld.Split("_")[4]
```

But I want to do that in one line.

So I tried:

```
$fld = $str | Where { $_.Contains("vrr") } | -split[4]
```

But this probably not the right way.
Any suggestions?

Comment: please see my edit

Answer (score 0):

You could do that with a regex. In case it doesn't contain `vrr`, the output is empty:

```
[regex]::Match('bla_sdf_r1_vrdr_1.0.1', '.*vrr_(.*)').Groups[1].Value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Regex](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2007.11.powershell.aspx).

```
"bla_sdf_r1_vrr_1.0.1" -match "[\d\.]*$"
```

It searches your string for digits and `.` as many times as possible in the end of the string.

Your result is in the [automatic variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx) `$matches[0]`

Edit:
Given your collection, you could do something like this:

```
$str | ForEach-Object { if($_ -match "[\d\.]*$") { $matches[0] } }
```

If the current string matches the regex I wrote, print the match.

Comment: But the collection have 2 items and i need to search for vrr or trr not only take the version number

Comment: Why do you need to search for `vrr` and `trr`?
In both instances, you need the version number.

Comment: But how can i distinguished between the both ?

Answer (score 0):

you can group the matches and access them by number (or also name them)

```
$str = "bla_sdf_r1_vrr_1.0.1", "bla_sdf_r1_trr_1.0.2"
$str | %{
  if ($_ -match '(vrr|trr)_([0-9.]+)') {
    $matches[1] + " is " + $matches[2]
  }
}
```

Output

```
vrr is 1.0.1
trr is 1.0.2
```

The output will be the same with this variant:

```
$str = "bla_sdf_r1_vrr_1.0.1", "bla_sdf_r1_trr_1.0.2"
$str | %{
  if ($_ -match '(?<xrr>vrr|trr)_(?<version>[0-9.]+)') {
    $matches.xrr + " is " + $matches.version
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "bla_sdf_r1_vrr_1.0.1", "bla_sdf_r1_trr_1.0.2"

$str | where {($_ -split "_")[3] -in ("vrr", "trr") } | select @{N="Type";E={($_ -split "_")[3]}}, @{N="Version";E={($_ -split "_")[4]}}
```